# How to correctly prepare and setting preloaded sbt lib

Tags: scala, sbt

In my situation, I cannot access internet in my office linux server. Therefore, I installed sbt in my personal computer. I followed instructions on sbt official web-site and run/compile a "hello world" for getting all dependency data.

Then, I copied **~/.ivy2** and **~/.sbt** and **sbt bin folders** to my offline office desktop. But when I run sbt, I got these errors:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.9 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_25)
[info] loading project definition from /proj/mtk07847/test/scala/project
[info] Updating
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.12
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   download error: Caught java.net.SocketException: Connection reset (Connection reset) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/s
cala-lang/scala-library/2.12.12/scala-library-2.12.12.pom
[error]   not found: ~/.ivy2/localorg.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.12/ivys/ivy.xml
...
```

It seems that sbt tried to download missing scala-library:2.12.12 which I already prepared.
In my ~/.ivy2 folder，the structure and path looks like the following:

```
~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.12.jar
~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/ivy-2.12.12.xml
~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/ivy-2.12.12.xml.original
~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/ivydata-2.12.12.properties
```

which is different from above messages:

**[error]   not found: ~/.ivy2/localorg.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.12/ivys/ivy.xml**

should I modified any describing files to indicate searching path or rule for sbt? or this method
is totally wrong (if so, can anyone know the flow guide me the better way?)

Comment: What's your goal here? Why do you even need SBT on your server? You usually package your app and it's dependencies from your personal machine and send the (autonomous) package to the server.

Comment: sorry for my Improper words, the linux server here just means my office laptop. I need sbt for my development, but my office laptop can only access to internal network. (sbt cat not update as usual way)

Comment: Then it feels very optimistic to work on a project without access to internet: every time you need to add a new dependency you would copy it from your personal machine? I'd rather ask your workplace for access to internet one way or the other.

Comment: Normally in a restricted corporate environment like this, one runs a proxy Artifactory and resolves artifacts from there.